# God consciousness and prayers

Tags: shiva, mantras

As I've read that there are different types of gods; some having physical forms(demi gods) and some having no forms and the Supreme one being BRAHMAN.

Does this mean that all these categories of divine beings can hear or be conscious of prayers of human beings  and tapasya?

For example lets say a devotee prays to lord Shiva or Rudra by repeating some mantra for some fruit. Then considering his devotion is very strong, do Shiva/Rudra becomes conscious of this prayers himself and give some fruits or merits to the prayer either it be knowledge, peace or power?